# calling a derived class method on a object cast to base class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a base class `Element` and a derived class `ViewSheet`. When I am collecting all of my `ViewSheet` objects they are being cast to `Element` by the collector method. Now I need to call a method on each object called `ViewSheet.get_Parameter()`. That method only exists on a derived class so cannot be called on `Element`.

I can find out what derived type is from calling `Element.GetType()` but then how can I actually cast that object to `ViewSheet` and then call the `ViewSheet.get_Parameter()` on it?

Since this happens a lot, I would need to implement some sort of generic method that could accept different base class + derived class combinations. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Example of collector method:

```
`ICollection<Element> allElements = 
    new FilteredElementCollector(activeDoc)
    .OfCategory(someCategory)
    .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
    .ToElements();
```

This always returns object collection of `Element` since thats the base class for all objects that I am dealing with. I could do a Linq cast during that collection but I would need to know that based on my Category I would be collecting specific type of objects which I do not now at the outset. Only when I actually collect all `Element` objects and call `GetType()` do I know what type I am dealing with.

Comment: Can you post a small bit of example code showing your collector method and how you use it? Just a wild guess though you could use the cast method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `as` to cast `AElement`. If the cast is successfull, `PossibleViewSheet` is not null and you can call the `get_Parameter()`

```
ViewSheet PossibleViewSheet = AElement as ViewSheet;

if (PossibleViewSheet != null)
{
  PossibleViewSheet.get_Parameter();
}
```

If you have many different concrete classes, you have to define an interface

```
public interface IGetParameter
{
  int get_Parameter();
}
```

Implement the interface to all needed classes and use the `as`-Operator with the interface like

```
IGetParameter PossibleGetParameter = AElement as IGetParameter;

if (PossibleGetParameter != null)
{
  PossibleGetParameter.get_Parameter();
}
```

Thrid way is to use reflection to get the method by name like

```
try
{
  AElement.GetType().GetMethod("get_Parameter").Invoke(AElement, null);
}
catch(Exception)
{
  //Method is not available
}
```

If your `get_Parameter()` requires one or more parameters (`get_Parameter(int definition, ...)`), add an object array with the paremeter(s) like

```
AElement.GetType().GetMethod("get_Parameter").Invoke(AElement, new object[] { definition, ... });
```

Comment: Would be even better to define an interface such as `IViewSheet`.

Comment: There is hundreds of possible base classes/derived classes combinations. I cannot check them all in that fashion.

Comment: Then you ave to use a interface. I will update my answer!

Comment: Whatever type you are checking, using an interface greatly simplifies the process: you will need to remember/use only a few of them.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg I like the reflection method, but I forgot to mention that get_Parameter() is called with an argument like viewSheet.get_Parameter(definition). How can i modify the invoke part to handle that?

Comment: I added a line of code to my answer to solve this problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking all sorts of good design and OOP rules trying to do what you are doing. If you want to use a "base class", it should contain all the virtual methods that the derived classes need to implement. If it doesn't, your "base class" is too low on the hierarchy.

Comment: This really isn't an answer.  It's more of a comment.

Comment: @juharr, I told him he needs a common base class and to use virtual methods. All the other "answers" say to do is / cast which is just plain dumb.

Comment: I am dealing with someone else's classes so I can't really go in and re-define how they are made. Can i?

Comment: @konrad -- I re-read your question, are you only concerned about ViewSheet? Or are there other classes and different methods you need to call? I.e. ViewSheet.getParameter() / SomeOtherObj.getSomeOtherValue()?

Comment: different objects but the method should always be the same.

Comment: @konrad, Ok, well, you'd have to use reflection or expression trees. Since you said there are hundreds of classes, I'd recommend building a generic method that takes in the type and returns a compiled lambda for you since you'll have to create one based on each class type if there is no common base class. Be sure to cache the lambdas Type <-> lambda if you are going to reuse them since they are expression to create, but much faster then reflection to call repeatedly.